# How can I delay submit

Tags: javascript, html, submit

How can I delay submit until the audio file finished because when submit event-triggered the page refreshed without playing the sound file
I've tried this but it's not working.

```
<form action="/game1/" method="POST" onsubmit="checkAnswer()">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="UserSorce" id="us" >
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl">
          Check
        </button>
      </form>
```

```
function checkAnswer()
  {
    let tmp=document.getElementById("answer").innerText;
    if(correctAns==tmp)
    { 
        document.getElementById("result").src=picCorrect;
        document.getElementById("result").style.display="block";
        var audio = new Audio(soundCorrect);
        audio.play();
        audio.onended = function () {
          return true;
        }
    }else{
        document.getElementById("result").src=picIncorrect;
        document.getElementById("result").style.display="block";
        var audio = new Audio(soundIncorrect);
        audio.play();  
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried the "duration" property?

Comment: What about using a plain button instead of a form?

Comment: Can you give me the syntax, please?

Comment: `<button type="button">`

Comment: Instead of the button type="submit", use type="button", then submit the form in `onended` handler.

Comment: I've done that same result :(

Comment: I highly doubt that would fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have all the stuff in place you need. The trick here is don't trigger the submission using the form's submit button. Instead add a simple html button, which calls `checkAnswer()`.

Inside the `checkAnswer()` function you are already listening for the audio's `onended` event. If that happened you can finally submit the form using it's `submit()` function.

A little something like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/game1/" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="UserSorce" id="us">
</form>
<button onclick="checkAnswer()">
  Check
</button>
```

and

```
function checkAnswer() {
  let tmp = document.getElementById("answer").innerText;
  if (correctAns == tmp) {
    document.getElementById("result").src = picCorrect;
    document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
    var audio = new Audio(soundCorrect);
    audio.onended = function() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
    audio.play();

  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").src = picIncorrect;
    document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
    var audio = new Audio(soundIncorrect);
    audio.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sir it's working you are the most amazing programmer I've ever seen
I really appreciate your help

Comment: Hehe - thanks for the kind words Stefano - glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi try handling the preventDefault on the submit event:

```
function checkAnswer(e)
  {

    e.preventDefault();

    let tmp=document.getElementById("answer").innerText;
    if(correctAns==tmp)
    { 
        document.getElementById("result").src=picCorrect;
        document.getElementById("result").style.display="block";
        var audio = new Audio(soundCorrect);
        audio.play();
        audio.onended = function () {
          return true;
        }
    }else{
        document.getElementById("result").src=picIncorrect;
        document.getElementById("result").style.display="block";
        var audio = new Audio(soundIncorrect);
        audio.play();  
    }
  }
```